# python: function with parameters and gather input then print return value

Tags: python

I'm currently going through beginner Python course in EDX and need help on one of its Required Coding Activity.

Program:

```
fishstore()
create and test fishstore()

fishstore() takes 2 string arguments: fish & price
fishstore returns a string in sentence form
gather input for fish_entry and price_entry to use in calling fishstore()
print the return value of fishstore()

example of output: Fish Type: Guppy costs $1
```

Comment: So what's the question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

```
def fishstore():
    fish_entry = input("Input fish ")
    price_entry = input("Input price ")  
    return "Fish Type: " +str(fish_entry) + " costs " + str(price_entry)
a = fishstore()
print (a)
```

This is the whole code... What part did you not understand?

Comment: when I ran your code it didnt ask for input.  i need the code to prompt me Input fish and Input price and then when I enter Gruppy for Input fish and 1 for Input price, it should return this output: Fish Type: Gruppy costs $1

Comment: How about now? i removed the arguments. I put the input inside the function. You can put back the arguments and take inputs outside the function(the inputs will be the arguments for the function)

Answer (score 0):

```
def fishstore(fish,price):

    return ("Fish Type: "+ fish.capitalize() + " costs $" + price)

fish_entry=input('Enter fish type: ')
price_entry=input('Enter fish type price: ')
print (fishstore(fish_entry,price_entry))
```

This one works.